# RemovedInDjango19Warning - isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting the following error when importing the models module in Django.

```
/Users/markcollier/Documents/Adapt/Taboo/TabooAPI/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py:161: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
```

class ContentType(models.Model):

I have searched around and tried all of the suggested solutions to similar problems.

I think it has something to do with how my settings.py file is set up but could be wrong. All help would be much appreciated.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

'django.contrib.sites',
'rest_framework',
'api.apps.ApiConfig',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'api.permissions.IsOwner',
)
}

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

apps.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.apps import AppConfig


class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'api'
```

directory structure:

```
django_api
    api
        __init__.py
        apps.py

    migrations

    models.py
    permissions.py
    serializers.py
    signals.py
    temp.py
    urls.py
    views.py

    datasets

    django_site
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py

    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
```

Comment: Define an attribute `label` for your app in addition to the `name`.

Comment: Tried the following:
`
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.apps import AppConfig


class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'api'
    label = 'djangoapi'
`
Still getting the same error.

Comment: can you post your `directory structure`

Comment: 'django.contrib.contenttypes', should be the first in INSTALLED_APPS list, it is important

Comment: @KlausD: the error comes from a Django builtin app, he can't just give it a label.

Comment: @FeroxTL I tried your suggestion and that didn't fix it.

Comment: @mahendra kamble added.

Answer (score 2):

According to the error message you posted, the problem is not with your own app but with `django.contrib.django.contenttypes.models.ContentType` - and googling for this exact error message shows you're not the first having this issue.

Since contenttypes is in your installed apps, the problem comes from contenttype being imported before being "officialy" loaded. So what you need know is to find out where contenttype is imported and which of these imports happens too soon - or just first try to place it first in your settings INSTALLED_APPS as FeroxTL suggest, it might (or not) solve the problem.